# display posts, pages and custom post types from another wordpress site

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, customization, api, feed

I have 2 sites one acting as a parent and the second acting as a branch of the organization. The sites are on different domains and databases.

I want to display on the branch site some posts and custom posts types (including images, and some advanced custom fields (ACF)) of specific categories from the parent site. I don't need to create/sync them on the branch site. Any edits or new posts will be only done on the parent site. The branch site will only reflect what is on the parent.

Any ideas how can I achieve this? I heard about RSS feeds but I'm not sure how to get started and if it works with images and ACF.

Thanks!

Comment: One option as you mentioned is to use RSS. You'lle need to use `add_feed()`, https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_feed/, function to register a custom feed. Another option is to register a custom REST endpoint, https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/, and fetch the content for example with js on the second site. In both cases you'd create a custom callback which you can use to query/format/return posts and related content as needed.

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a try.